# Calling an openCV based Dll from Labview

Tags: opencv, dll, labview

I'm trying to call a simple openCV based Dll in LabVIEW and keep getting the "library not found or failed to load" error.

I use LabVIEW 64bit, and the Dll was built in C++ for 64bit. Its function is just to flip an image horizontally.
I tried to copy opencv_world470.dll and opencv_world470d.dll everywhere. to the same directory as my Dll, to system32, and to the directory where LabVIEW.exe is located. I added their directory to the PATH in the environmental variables, and still it doesn't work.
When I run dumpbin on my Dll, it lists the following dependencies:
opencv_world470d.dll
opencv_world470.dll
VCRUNTIME140.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
KERNEL32.dll
I tried to run another Dll that just sums two numbers and returns the result, and it works without problems. This simple Dll just uses the bottom three dependencies according to dumpbin.
Why doens't LabVIEW find the openCV dependencies? or is it some other problem?
I plan to use more openCV Dlls in the future so ideally I would prefer to leave the openCV libraries dynamic and not static.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. But when I changed the machine it worked. So I checked on few other machines to ensure its not my system problem.
Figured out the solution, add opencv dlls to the debug folder of your project, where your cpp dll is located.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing that you linked with release and debug versions at the same time is you mentioned that you dependent from opencv_world470d.dll and opencv_world470.dll.
In general it is not very complicated to develop simple wrapper, the code for 8 bit gray image looks something like this:

```c
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Flip(void *img, short Width, short Height, int FlipMode)
{
    try{
        Mat Image(Size(Width, Height), CV_8U, img, Width);
        flip(Image, Image, FlipMode);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        return 1; //OpenCV Error occurred
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I placed small project: https://github.com/AndrDm/OpenCVFlipDemoLV, may be it will be helpful for you or someone else.
Andrey.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to use OpenCV with the EMGU .NET wrapper and LabVIEW. Some of the functions require delegates, LV doesn't support them, but the main MAT functions work.